# Counting switching functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

By using 16 bit binary in BCD , how many switching functions can exist ?

Now , since this is BCD anything above 1001 is invalid.
Considering 16 bits : 1001 1001 1001 1001

Above is number of possible combinations : 0 - 9999 
There are 10^4 possible combinations.
Number of switching functions : 2^(10^4)

Answer given is (10^4). Am I missing something obvious ?

Comment: What is a "switching function"?

Comment: Boolean function (or switching function) is a function of the form ƒ : Bk → B, where B = {0, 1} {wikipedia}

Comment: Okay. No further conditions means you're right. You can accept joriki's answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right and they're wrong.

Comment: I'd gladly accept this , If there are no further counter arguments from anyone else.